# Junk characters coming in from pinvoke WM_GETTEXT

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I have a method set that uses pinvoke to call WM_GETTEXT on another program's textbox - and it works fairly well, but frequently I just get back total junk text appended to the end of it. (The ORIGINAL text is always intact.)

This is random, I cannot reproduce it on demand, but it is frequent enough to be stopship.

Here is the text to get the information.

```
System.Text.StringBuilder strBuffer = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

int nLen = 0;

bool nUpdated = false;

try
{
    this.isOpen = false;

    if (ptrHandle == null)
        return;

    if (ptrHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        return;

    nLen =
        Converter.SendMessage(ptrHandle, Converter.WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);

    if (nLen <= 0)
        return;

    if (nPreviousLen != nLen)
        nUpdated = true;

    if (nUpdated)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("nLen:\t{0}", nLen);

        strBuffer = new System.Text.StringBuilder(null, nLen + 1);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("strBuffer:\t{0}", strBuffer.ToString());

        int sLen = Converter.SendMessageByString(ptrHandle, Converter.WM_GETTEXT, nLen
            , strBuffer);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("sLen:\t{0}", sLen);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\n\nstrBuffern\n\n{0}", strBuffer.ToString());

        strBuffer = new System.Text.StringBuilder(strBuffer.ToString().Left(sLen));

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\n\nsLenBuffer\n\n{0}", strBuffer.ToString());

source = new Special.IO.TextReader( 
                    new System.IO.MemoryStream(  System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strBuffer.ToString() ) ), nUpdated );
        }
    }
}


    /// <summary>
    /// Sends the specified message to a window or windows. The SendMessage function calls the window procedure for the specified window and does not return until the window procedure has processed the message.
    /// <br />
    /// To send a message and return immediately, use the SendMessageCallback or SendNotifyMessage function. To post a message to a thread's message queue and return immediately, use the PostMessage or PostThreadMessage function.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hWnd">
    /// Handle to the window whose window procedure will receive the message. 
    /// If this parameter is HWND_BROADCAST, the message is sent to all top-level windows in the system, including disabled or invisible unowned windows, overlapped windows, and pop-up windows; but the message is not sent to child windows.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="Msg">
    /// [in] Specifies the message to be sent.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="wParam">
    /// [in] Specifies additional message-specific information.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="lParam">
    /// [in] Specifies additional message-specific information.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The return value specifies the result of the message processing; it depends on the message sent.
    /// </returns>
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessageA", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = false)]
    internal static extern int SendMessageByString(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, StringBuilder lParam);

    /// <summary>
    /// Sends the specified message to a window or windows. The SendMessage function calls the window procedure for the specified window and does not return until the window procedure has processed the message.
    /// <br />
    /// To send a message and return immediately, use the SendMessageCallback or SendNotifyMessage function. To post a message to a thread's message queue and return immediately, use the PostMessage or PostThreadMessage function.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hWnd">
    /// Handle to the window whose window procedure will receive the message. 
    /// If this parameter is HWND_BROADCAST, the message is sent to all top-level windows in the system, including disabled or invisible unowned windows, overlapped windows, and pop-up windows; but the message is not sent to child windows.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="Msg">
    /// [in] Specifies the message to be sent.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="wParam">
    /// [in] Specifies additional message-specific information.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="lParam">
    /// [in] Specifies additional message-specific information.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The return value specifies the result of the message processing; it depends on the message sent.
    /// </returns>
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

Comment: Do you have to bother with the WM_GETTEXTLENGTH step? Can't you just get analyze the StringBuilder after the fact to see if it contains any data? You don't have to declare StringBuilder with a particular size. See this bit about marshalling StringBUilder: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164193.aspx#S4

Comment: But the nLen+1 in the SendMessageByString seems to be required. What do I put there if I don't get the length earlier?

Comment: Yes, I have to do the GETTEXTLENGTH. The length is required in the sendmessage method.

Comment: Can you set it to be an arbitrarily large value? Say 256 or something or does it have to be exact? (I'm trying to help you avoid the get length msg because in the span between the two messages is where the memory might be getting wacky.)

Comment: The size of the text received each time is going to be different, I think. Can you explain what avoiding it would do?

Comment: It grows as the program continues to run, and each time it grows, the value is random. It is impossible to determine the value arbitrarily.

Comment: if I could read from the bottom up, I can use a static number. But I do not know how to do this.

Comment: Assuming ptrHandle is an IntPtr, you can remove `if (ptrHandle == null) return;`. An IntPtr is an integer, and will never be equal to a null reference; so your condition is always false. The compiler actually won't generate any IL for that `if` statement because it can tell it will never execute (you can verify this in Reflector).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some-thing weird going on with this, it looks like the control you are targeting, when using P/Invoke via WM_GETTEXT is returning the junk... I suggest the following, instead of returning the whole buffer, return back the current line which would make things a bit snappier...

```
try{
    int nLineCount = Converter.SendMessage(ptrHandle, Converter.EM_GETLINECOUNT, 0, 0);
    int nIndex = Converter.SendMessage(ptrHandle, Converter.EM_LINEINDEX, nLineCount, 0);
    int nLineLen = Converter.SendMessage(ptrHandle, Converter.EM_LINELENGTH, nIndex, 0);
    //
    strBuffer = new System.Text.StringBuilder(nLineLen);
    strBuffer.Append(Convert.ToChar(nLineLen));
    strBuffer.Length = nLineLen;
    int nCharCnt = Converter.SendMessage(ptrHandle, Converter.EM_GETLINE, new IntPtr(nLineCount),     strBuffer).ToInt32();
    nLen = nCharCnt;
    if (nLen <= 0) return;
    if (nPreviousLen != nLen) nUpdated = true;
}finally{
    source = new TextReader(strBuffer.ToString(), nUpdated, isOpen ? true : false);
    this.isOpen = true;
    nPreviousLen = nLen;
}
```

In that way, we obtain:

- the line count in the control - `nLineCount`
- Obtain the character index that is the start of the line `nLineCount` - `nIndex`
- Finally, obtain the line length using the `nIndex` - `nLineLen`

Using `nLineLen`, then we can set up the StringBuilder buffer, the tricky part in using EM_GETLINE is, the zero'th position of the buffer **MUST** contain the length in char's - hence the usage of `strBuffer.Append(Convert.ToChar(nLineLen))`, and the stringbuilder's `Length` property specified.

Here are the constants required for the above P/Invoke

- const int EM_GETLINECOUNT = 0xBA;
- const int EM_LINEINDEX = 0xBB;
- const int EM_LINELENGTH = 0xC1;

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't ignore the return value when you send WM_GETTEXT. From MSDN:

> [The return value is the number of characters copied, not including the terminating null character.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632627(VS.85).aspx)

If the other app changes the control's text (to something shorter) between your WM_GETTEXTLENGTH and your WM_GETTEXT, then that would explain what you're seeing: WM_GETTEXT fills the first (let's say) 5 characters of your 20-character StringBuilder, and the rest is undefined. It might have null characters or it might have garbage (depends on things like whether you're calling the ANSI version of SendMessage, which would force the OS to allocate a probably-garbage-filled temporary buffer on your behalf), but either way, you need to strip them off before you use the string.

You need to read the return value of your SendMessageByString call, and truncate the StringBuilder to that length before using it.

Comment: I thought this had fixed it - but no, it still does the same thing.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted all your code, including both this fix and your P/Invoke declarations.

Comment: I have posted it as you asked.

Comment: Are you running this on a 64-bit OS? If so, the problem might be your P/Invoke declaration for SendMessageByString. According to http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendMessage.html, both the wParam and the return value should be IntPtr, not int.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you're working so hard to force this to use the ANSI version of SendMessage? If you run this on an NT-based OS (i.e., anything newer than Windows 95 or 98), you're forcing the OS to do extra work to convert the control's Unicode text into ANSI -- and then you're turning around and changing the ANSI text right back to Unicode (since all .NET strings are Unicode). That conversion (and the temp buffer the OS has to allocate to do it) might be part of the reason for the garbage. Try changing SendMessageByString's EntryPoint to "SendMessage" and CharSet to CharSet.Auto.

Comment: I am using a 64-bit OS, but some of my users will be on 32-bit. Does this make a difference? I am not trying to 'force' anything. I am an amateur at best with this, and I am copying what I have found online and read in books. Let me try what you have suggested, and get back to you.

Comment: I have updated my code as you suggested and posted it in a new 'answer' to this thread.

Comment: Alright, even with the updated code, I am experiencing the same problem.

Comment: I really don't know what to do. This is extremely important. It just isn't working... It still produces junk at random.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your error is in the wrong usage of one parameter of `WM_GETTEXT` message. You should use `nLen + 1` instead of `nLen` as the `wParam`.

At the beginning you use `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH` to get `nLen`, which will be the number of TCHARs copied, **not including the terminating null character**. Then you allocate the buffer of the size `nLen + 1` characters. There steps are absolutely correctly, but then you send `WM_GETTEXT` with `nLen` as the `wParam` which is wrong, because corresponds to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632627.aspx `wParam` must contain the maximum number of characters to be copied, **including the terminating null character**. So the correct parameter of `WM_GETTEXT` message must be `nLen + 1` instead of `nLen`.

The usage of the buffer which are **larger** as `nLen` I find for the best way. I'll recommend you to allocate buffer at least 2 characters longer as the `nLen` value returned by `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH` and use `nLen + 2` as the parameter of `WM_GETTEXT` (exactly how large are you buffer size). If the returned value of the `WM_GETTEXT` are `nLen` or less, then you can be sure that the returned string contain full text which you want to read. If the result of `WM_GETTEXT` will be `nLen + 1`, then the text are changed between sending of `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH` and `WM_GETTEXT` messages and you should repeat all the steps starting with `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH` one more time to know the new text size.

Comment: If you find an example how your results can be reproduced your problem will be quickly solved. Independent on this you should agree: 1) you should use at least `nLen+1` as a `wParam` instead of `nLen` for `WM_GETTEXT` 2) only if the value returned by `WM_GETTEXT` is more as one less then `wParam` (the buffer size) which you send, then you can be sure that returned data contain the full text which you try read by `WM_GETTEXT` message.